# UWP In-App Notifications (As opposed to Toast notifications)

Tags: notifications, uwp, toast

On Android, toast notifications work differently to UWP. It simply shows a little black popup message over the top of the app. In UWP, toast notifications are indistinguishable from push notifications from the user perspective. Is there a ***standardized*** way in UWP to simply show a quick notification inside the app that will disappear after a few seconds and not interfere with the user's experience? I mean without it looking like the user has received a push notification?

This article doesn't seem to hint at anything like what I am talking about.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-badges-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up building something as part of our Xamarin UI library to handle this.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/blob/master/Adapt.Presentation.UWP/Adapt/Presentation/UWP/InAppNotification.xaml.cs

There is a sample in this repo:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

Note: *the same is for Xamarin Forms, but if you crack the code open, you'll be able to figure out how to use this for any UWP app.*

Comment: I guess some one cracked the code too hard, the link does not exist anymore.

Comment: I found it here using the name: https://github.com/deathwind/Adapt.Presentation

Answer (score 6):

The UWP Toolkit provides an InAppNotifications control for this.

http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/InAppNotification/

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) class supersedes Toast. While Toast is currently still supported, Snackbar is now the preferred way to display brief, transient messages to the user.

Take a look at [Showing Pop-Up Messages](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/index.html) to find out the most common use cases.

Comment: The question is in regards to UWP. Android isn't the issue, but I'll take this in to account for Android.