# How to show simple informative message for few seconds on certain action in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my app I want to show success message when user performs certain action such as "Adding a file" or moving file. I have my task in ViewModel and on successful completion of task I want to show "Task successfully completed" in middle of the window screen

Comment: IIs this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167129/uwp-in-app-notifications-as-opposed-to-toast-notifications?rq=1

Comment: Yes that is my exact requirement. But I couldn't find code in the githud link provided there and also I could find reference for UWP Toolkit InAppNotifictions

Comment: Any updates about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show an alert which shows the finish message, you could consider using [ContentDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-20348).

Here is a very simple usage:

```
private async void DisplayNoWifiDialog(){
ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
{
    Title = "Alert",
    Content = "Task successfully completed",
    CloseButtonText = "Ok"
};

await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();}
```

You could also make your own custom ContentDialog in Xaml. Please check the document for more information:[ContentDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-20348).

**Update:**

> I don't want to block the rest of UI and show it until user closes it. I just want it to come for few seconds and disappear

If you don't want the user action and make the alert disappear automatically, you just don't need to set the `CloseButtonText` value and then use a [DispatcherTimer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-20348) to hide the content dialog.

```
     private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog(){
            Title = "Alert",
            Content = "Task successfully completed",
        };

          CreateTimer();
        await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
       
    }

    public void CreateTimer() 
    {
        // get a timer to close the ContentDialog after 2s
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick; ;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        //hide the contentdialog
        noWifiDialog.Hide();
        // release the timer
        dispatcherTimer = null;
    }
```

Comment: But I don't want any user action on it. I don't want to block the rest of UI and show it until user closes it. I just want it to come for few seconds and disappear

Comment: I observed that there is [InAppNotifiction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification) control which simplies and adhers to my requirement. But when I add <controls:InAppNotification> it is saying InAppNotification doesn't exist, missed assembly reference something like that.

Comment: The above solution doesn't work. On executing this line *_await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();_ dialog is shown and the app is struck. There is no way to close the dialog without close button. _CreateTimer()_ isn't executed at all.

Comment: @Nisha I adjusted the code, call the `CreateTimer();`  before showing the contentdialog. Then it should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `InfoBar`, which is the native WinUI control for doing just that. Although in a normal context I don't recommend showing the user that the task completed successfully every single time.

for instance:

```
<muxc:InfoBar Severity="Success" Title="Task completed successfully!" Message="optional, if you want to show additional secondary information"/>
```